# How to select TextBox on Label Click

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

In Microsoft Access, when you click on a label, the textbox associated with that label gets the focus.  As far as I can tell, VB.NET does not have this same functionality.  I know I can always add something in to the click event of the label, like so...

```
TextBox1.Focus()
```

But I have dozens of fields on the form, and it would make it so much easier if I did not need to add this to the click event of each label.

I guess it would be possible to make an event for all labels that forces a tab to the next control, and assuming that I have the Tab indices set up correctly, then this would work.  The problem would occur when adding new fields to the form, in which case all tab indices would need re-verified.

```
Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click, Label2.Click
    'code to tab to next field...
End Sub
```

Is there any easier way?

Comment: @Raging Bull.  1 label for each textbox.  Plus some label/other control (combobox, dateTimePicker,etc.) combinations. I figure if I can work out the textbox issue, then the other controls should follow suit.

Comment: So you want to set focus to the next control (like pressing tab key) when any label is clicked, right?

Comment: @Raging Bull.  Basically, but please see the comment above where adding additional fields (which happens a LOT with this program) would necessitate verifying all of the tab indices again.

Comment: The important thing is that when you add a new control you add also a new label for it setting their respective tabindex without colliding with other controls. Doesn't seems too much a burden to me

Comment: Consider putting a Label and a TextBox into a UserControl.

Comment: @Steve.  It isn't a burden; I could easily do that.  I was just curious if there is an "easy" way to do this by setting a Property or something similar.  As an example, if you could possibly set focus to a label on mouse click, then it would see that there is no TabStop on the label and automatically tab to the next control that does have a TabStop.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way for this. You should code it. I am trying to translate a little method from C# to VB.NET

Comment: @LarsTech.  Intriguing idea.  I don't want to have to redo all of these databound controls though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, set the controls' TabIndex orders on your form then use this code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf c Is Label Then AddHandler c.Click, AddressOf Label_Click
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Me.SelectNextControl(sender, True, True, True, True)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now whenever you click on a label, the following control in the order will be focused.

Comment: Thanks.  I just added that exact same code and getting ready to test.

Comment: It seems like this is the only way to do this in .NET (unless someone comes up with a great solution).  The only thing different in my code than this solution is that I am recursively looking for labels to deal with those pesky children containers.

Comment: @aly-el-haddad You beat me to it, I was about to submit the same thing, lol. It's a great solution, but there is only one downside which APrough should be made aware of: if you add, remove or rearrange any of the controls, you wil need to redo the Tab order

Comment: @Grahamvs.  Yep.  Already aware.  Sure wish there was an easier way, but this will have to do for now.

Comment: @APrough well, for an over the top approach, you could always create a new control that contains a label and the type of control you require. Then on the `label` `click event`, set focus to the `textbox` (or whatever control you used). That way you don't have to worry about setting the tab order :)

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a dictionary where the label is the key and the control to focus is the value, then add a Click event handler to all of the label in the Dictionary. Everytime you add a label/control 'all' you need to do is add another KeyValuePair to the Dictionary

Simple Example:

```
 Public Class Form1
    Protected Friend DicLabelToControl As Dictionary(Of Label, Control)

    Protected Friend Sub InitLabelDic()
        DicLabelToControl = New Dictionary(Of Label, Control) From {{Label1, TextBox1}, {Label2, TextBox2}}
    End Sub

    Protected Friend Sub AddClickEventsToLabels()
        For Each lb As Label In DicLabelToControl.Keys
            AddHandler lb.Click, AddressOf HandleLabelClick
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleLabelClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        DicLabelToControl(CType(sender, Label)).Focus()

    End Sub



    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        InitLabelDic()
        AddClickEventsToLabels()
    End Sub
End Class
```